# GLFW is not initializing window (LWJGL)

Tags: java, lwjgl, glfw

I am new to using LWJGL (and relatively so to Java in general) and as such, I was reading their [page on getting started](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide) where they supplied an example Hello World program. I tried to run it myself and found that it errored with the following:
`2020-03-18 10:20:02.145 java[19779:1119716] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.`

I was confused as to what this meant because I didn't think the `init()` method was running in any thread other than main, and so I added a line to print which thread it was running in, and sure enough, it printed `Thread[main,5,main]`.

What is going on here, and how can I fix it?

The full code is below for context.

```
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;

import java.nio.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    // The window handle
    private long window;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

        init();
        loop();

        // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if ( !glfwInit() )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        // Configure GLFW
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

        // This should be running on main?
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());

        // Create the window -- This is where the problem is
        window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
        });

        // Get the thread stack and push a new frame
        try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
            IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
            IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

            // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
            glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

            // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
            GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

            // Center the window
            glfwSetWindowPos(
                    window,
                    (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                    (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
            );
        } // the stack frame is popped automatically

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    private void loop() {
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
        // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
        // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
        // bindings available for use.
        GL.createCapabilities();

        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
        // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
        while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) ) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

            // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
            // invoked during this call.
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld().run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be multiple issues with the example presented by the LWJGl3.org group.

1> The  glfwInit() function call may need to be called a good deal earlier.  this function needs to be called before other LWJGL function calls according to the library documentation.


1.1> Suggestion: place the call in the main()

 public static void main(String[] args) {

         glfwInit();

         .....

1.2 OR- Suggestion: place it by itself as the first statement of the init() function


private void init() {
 
    glfwInit();
 
    ....

1.3>OR- Suggestion:Create a class constructor and place the glfwInit(); function call in it so you are guaranteed that it is call early.

2> The import static declarations may need to be be altered

2.1> Suggestion: Try

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.* ;    //  fires glfwInit;

//not helpful import static  org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSetKeyCallback;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSetKeyCallback;

//import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback.*;  //fails to do any thing

3> Give the "window" class variable a unique name in its declaration to avoid name collisions with the "window" associated with the Lambda function call --discussed later.

3.1 Suggestion:

 // The window handle

     private long windowid;

4> The init() function needs to have "local variable declarations;

int key;

int scancode;

int action ;

int mods;

5> The example as presented employs the new JRE8 feature Lambda function syntax:  () -> trick. However Lambda functions are not "supported" for Eclipse 3.8.1 (ubuntu 16.04) already running on JRE8 but with Java SDK compliance set by default to 1.7.  That required substantial child-birthing to move to Eclipse 2020-6R.  Unfortunately, the effort is now in my Limbo like CPM86.

5.1> A "possible" work around may evolve from following Warmful Development's Setting up LWJGL 3 with Eclipse video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VH9KAhjXVFM.  The plan is to scan his series to see if a possible solution can evolve to my specific need.

Comment: No joy with my efforts to upgrade from Eclipse 3.8.1 to Eclipse 2020_06R.  I am done with this Lambda function approach and moving to the next soirée.

Comment: I have the F310 - LWJGL working well in Eclipse 3.8.1.  I found a helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixQLcLxJLRc.  The host is presenting in German.  My German is not the best, but I masked it with "mute" and streaming classical music.  I had to take a number of screen snap shoots to capture the salient points.  But it worked once I had all the "user libraries".